# Cuban ferry services to other countries

Tags: budget, ferries, cuba, jamaica, bahamas

Are there any sail/ferry services that (in the case of sailing, don't require you to be a crew member) will take you to and from Cuba to the various islands and countries around Cuba.

A few of the countries I would like to visit while in Cuba are:

- Jamaica
- The Bahamas
- Turks and Caicos

I'm not bothered about visitng all of them, one of them would be fine due to the amount of time i have for holiday and probably sail time.  I'd be looking to do this on a budget of under $50 per person for a return trip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Wikitravel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Cuba#Get_in):

> There are no regular ferries or boats to Cuba from foreign ports,
>   although some cruise liners do visit. Yachters are expected to anchor
>   at the public marinas. Most ports are closed and tourists are not
>   permitted to walk around them. Private vessels may enter at Marina
>   Hemingway in Havana or Marina Acua in Varadero. There are no visa
>   requirements. Expect to hand out several $10 bills to facilitate your
>   entry.